# Use linking to open apk with react-native

Tags: android, android-intent, react-native

I am trying to initiate an apk installation on android with my react-native app. I tried using this code with url a remote url of the apk

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
 });
```

With this code the app opens chrome download the apk and then allow the user to install it. My goal is to use itent to directly ask the user, within my app, if he wants to install the new app.

I used RNFS to download the app and store it on the device, and then I used this code to install it

```
Linking.openURL(RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+'/test.apk').catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

But I get an error:

```
{"framesToPop":1,"code":"}
```

Do you know what is the problem or how could I fix that? Shall I specifiy the intent data type `application/vnd.android.package-archive` using Linking? and if yes, how?